# String to localdatetime doesnt retunr seconds "00"

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

I have a method that I take a startTime String and a endTime String convert to LocalDateTime and compare the hours difference between and generate the values in a ArrayList. For example if I have startTime: "2023-09-14T12:00:00",
endTime: "2023-09-14T14:00:00", the method will find the value 2023-09-14T13:00:00 and it will add it in the ArrayList. The problem is that when the values are converted from String to LocalDateTime the seconds doesnt appear in the format like this : 2023-09-14T13:00 .

```
 public static ArrayList<LocalDateTime> calculateHours(String startTime, tring endTime) {
        

        // Parse the combined strings to LocalDateTime
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startTime,formatter);
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(endTime,formatter);

        // Calculate the difference in hours
        long hoursDifference = java.time.Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime).toHours();

        // Create an ArrayList to store LocalDateTime objects
        ArrayList<LocalDateTime> hoursList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add each hour to the ArrayList with seconds included
        for (long i = 0; i < hoursDifference; i++) {
            LocalDateTime currentHour = startDateTime.plusHours(i);
            hoursList.add(currentHour);
        }
        return hoursList;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that when the values are converted from String to LocalDateTime the seconds doesnt appear in the format like this : 2023-09-14T13:00 ."

That's talking about a conversion back to string, which would use `LocalDateTime.toString()` by default - and that omits the seconds when the value is 0, [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString()). In other words, you can see the same behavior with

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 9, 14, 13, 0, 0);
System.out.println(ldt); // Prints 2023-09-14T13:00
```

In other words, nothing is going wrong - you're just misinterpreting however you're looking at the values in the list. If you need the values to be formatted in a specific way, you'll need to specify a `DateTimeFormatter` (such as the one you've already created) and call `ldt.format(formatter)`.

Comment: As you said I have already made a formatter and also as you I am using it. What's your solution for my problem I don't get it?

Comment: ldt.format(formatter) return String, my ArrayList<LocalDateTime> values.

Comment: @ChrisDamianidis: A `LocalDateTime` value doesn't have any notion of a formatter as part of its state, any more than an `int` knows whether it was parsed from hex or decimal for example. The value is just the value. You appear to be looking at a string representation of that value and expecting it to be in a particular format - if you want a particular format, you need to call `format` on the `LocalDateTime` and pass in that formatter. To put it another way: the values in your `ArrayList` are fine. You're just misinterpreting whatever is displaying them to you.

Comment: @ChrisDamianidis: If you wrote `ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(); integers.add(0x10);` and then displayed the `ArrayList` and saw the value 16, would you be confused? Because that's *exactly* equivalent to what's happening here.

Comment: @ChrisDamianidis: No, I've read your question carefully. I think you need to read my *answer and comments* more carefully. Nothing is going wrong in your parsing code. The seconds *aren't* being "lost" - you're just misinterpreting however you're displaying the results in the list. What you're seeing (and you haven't told us how you're displaying the list at all - in the debugger? in an app?) is the result of converting those LocalDateTime values *back* into strings, and I suspect that's using the default format, which *won't format a seconds value of 0*.

Comment: @ChrisDamianidis: If you think the problem is in the parsing, then look at the sample code I've written, or even change your own code to hard-code the LocalDateTime creation, so that there's no parsing involved at all. You'll still get the same result, because *the problem isn't in the parsing*. The problem is in your expectations of however you're displaying the values in the list.

Comment: @ChrisDamianidis: I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean by "I use the ArrayList later to setTime of an object so I have then to parse the given value by String with the correct formatter" - but it sounds like you missed a lot of context from your question. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints for next time. (I'm not sure whether you meant that *my* answer here could be simpler, or whether some change you needed to make in your code could be simpler...)